# logical operator && doesnt recognize on Type Script

Tags: typescript

I am trying to compare the next output in order to get the result that I want. Here is my code:

```
  if (this.bmi < 18.5 )
  {
    this.hasil="Berat badan kurang";
  } 
  else if (this.bmi >= 18.5 && this.bmi <=24)
  { 
    this.hasil = "Normal";
  } 
  else if (this.bmi >= 25 && this.bmi <=29 )
  {
    this.hasil = "Berat badan lebih";
  }
  else
  {
    this.hasil = "obesitas";
  }
  console.log(this.hasil);
  console.log(this.bmi);    


})`
```

`this.bmi` was a number and `this.hasil` was a `string`
on that code the `&&` operator did not recognize and it just gives a result between the `if` and `else` that contains one condition

Comment: This isn't entirely clear.  What *specific* behaviour are you observing (input + output), and what behaviour did you expect?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

I have created a working example of your code and the `&&` are recognized. However, I can see an error in your code.

You have a logical gap in your numbering between `24` and `25` (for example 24.1, 24.2, etc).

## Example Class

Here is the example class I wrapped your code with:

```
class Example {
    constructor(private bmi: number, private hasil: string) {}


    go() {
        console.log(this.hasil);

        if (this.bmi < 18.5) {
            this.hasil = "Berat badan kurang";
        }
        else if (this.bmi >= 18.5 && this.bmi <= 24) {
            this.hasil = "Normal";
        }
        else if (this.bmi >= 25 && this.bmi <= 29) {
            this.hasil = "Berat badan lebih";
        }
        else {
            this.hasil = "obesitas";
        }
        console.log(this.hasil, this.bmi);
    }
}
```

## Tests

And here are a number of test cases designed to work around all the edges:

```
new Example(18.4, 'Test 1').go();
new Example(18.5, 'Test 2').go();
new Example(18.6, 'Test 3').go();
new Example(24, 'Test 4').go();
new Example(24.1, 'Test 5').go(); // <--
new Example(24.9, 'Test 6').go(); // <--
new Example(25, 'Test 7').go();
new Example(29, 'Test 8').go();
new Example(29.1, 'Test 9').go();
```

Test 5 and Test 6 drop all the way through to `obesitas`, which might explain the problem you are having with your code. Essentially, the second block goes up to `this.bmi <= 24` but the next block starts at `this.bmi >= 25` causing the gap in your range.

Test output:

```
Test 1
Berat badan kurang 18.4

Test 2
Normal 18.5

Test 3
Normal 18.6

Test 4
Normal 24

Test 5
obesitas 24.1

Test 6
obesitas 24.9

Test 7
Berat badan lebih 25

Test 8
Berat badan lebih 29

Test 9
obesitas 29.1
```

## Implicit Range

One thing to consider when using an if-statement such as this is that if you got past the previous condition, you actually know if to be false, so you may be able to better express things in a way that you can't miss a range:

```
class Example {
    constructor(private bmi: number, private hasil: string) {}


    go() {
        console.log(this.hasil);

        if (this.bmi < 18.5) {
            this.hasil = "Berat badan kurang";
        }
        else if (this.bmi <= 24) {
            this.hasil = "Normal";
        }
        else if (this.bmi <= 29) {
            this.hasil = "Berat badan lebih";
        }
        else {
            this.hasil = "obesitas";
        }
        console.log(this.hasil, this.bmi);
    }
}
```